# How to get subplots of matplotlib Figure?

Tags: matplotlib

I know that I can use `plt.subplots()` to get handles for Figure and subplots at the same time, but how to get all subplots (or specific subplot) of an existing Figure instance?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If `figure` is a Figure instance you can get the axes inside it via

```
allaxes = fig.get_axes()
```

The return of this (`allaxes`)  is a list of all the axes inside the figure. Which subplot is which in this list, you need to know from the figure or some other source.